# Show that $δ_1([u]_1) = [e]_0−[f]_0$, where $e, f∈M_2(C_0(ℝ^2)^∼)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

Consider the short exact sequence $$0\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }C_0(ℝ^2)\xrightarrow{\ \varphi \ }C(ⅅ)\xrightarrow{\ \psi\ }C()\xrightarrow{\ \ \ }0,$$
where $\psi$ is the restriction mapping and $\varphi$ is obtained by identifying $\mathbb D\setminus\mathbb T$  with $ℝ^2$. We make the following identification for the unitisation $C_0(ℝ^2)^\sim$ of $C_0(ℝ^2)$
$$C_0(ℝ^2)^\sim = \{f∈C(ⅅ):\ f|_ \ \text{ is constant}\}.$$

Let $u∈C()$ be the element given by $u(z) =z$. Show that $δ_1([u]_1) = [e]_0−[f]_0$, where $e,f∈M_2(C_0(ℝ^2)^∼)$ are given at $z∈\mathbb D$ by
$$e(z) =\begin{bmatrix}\lvert z\rvert^2& z(1-\lvert z\rvert^2)^\frac{1}{2} \\\overline z(1-\lvert z\rvert^2)^\frac{1}{2}& 1-\lvert z\rvert^2\end{bmatrix},\qquad\qquad
f(z)=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

I am trying to show $δ_1([u]_1) = [e]_0−[f]_0$. Hhow can i do that? Any hint?

This is my try:

Applying the boundary map $δ_1$ to the class of $[]_1$. The boundary map $δ_1: K_1(C_0(ℝ^2)^∼)$$→ K_0(C()) $is defined as follows:
$δ_1([]_1)$ $= [ ∘ ]_0 - []_0$

Now, let's compute $ ∘ $ and substitute it into the formula.

$ ∘ $$:  → C()$
$( ∘ )()$$ =\psi(()) = () = $

Therefore, we have $( ∘ )()$$ = $ for all $ ∈ $.

Substituting the results back into the formula:
$δ_1([]_1)= []_0 - []_0$
To compute $[]_0$ and $[]_0$, we need to express them as matrices in $_2(C_0(ℝ^2)^∼)$.
$$[]_0 =\begin{bmatrix} & 0\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$[]_0 =\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Finally, we can compute $δ_1([]_1)$:
$δ_1([]_1)= []_0 - []_0$
=$\begin{bmatrix}& 0\\0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ - $\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$
=$\begin{bmatrix}& 0\\0& -1\end{bmatrix}$
Therefore, $δ_1([]_1) = \begin{bmatrix}& 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$
In conclusion, we have shown that $δ_1([]_1) =\begin{bmatrix}& 0\\0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$, which matches the expression for $[]_0 - []_0$ given in the problem statement.

Comment: When you write $\delta_1([u]_1)=[\psi\circ u]_0 - [\varphi]_0$, what does $[\varphi]_0$ even mean?